Ноги отстают от тела игрока (Ragdoll)
Делаю ragdoll-контроллер, начал делать анимации. Сделал анимацию ходьбы и начал ее проверять, когда игрок идет вперед, то все отлично, но когда начинает идти назад, то ноги начинают волочиться за туловищем. Пробовал настраивать joint, но безуспешно.
Вот ссылка на видео, на которых показана ходьба вперед и назад: https://files.fm/u/77znuzn3hp

https://imgur.com/a/NRyavyW вот ссылка на фото с настройками joint одной из ног

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
